# Should C++ attributes be in the header or the implementation or both?

Tags: c++

I have looked around quite a bit and have not found whether or not C++ attributes should be in the header or the implementation or both. For example:

`file.h`

```
[[nodiscard]] std::future<int> get_data();
```

`file.cpp`

```
[[nodiscard]] std::future<int> get_data() { return ...; }
```

Should both have the attribute or only one? The [examples provided by cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) are all functions with no forward declaration.

Comment: It's only declared in the header file, not defined. And IMHO I think that way of doing things is fairly ubiquitous. I'm leaving this as a comment because I don't know how to definitively answer this question

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To be effective, the attribute needs to be applied to the declaration (i.e., in the header). If a call is being compiled, and the declaration the compiler has seen lacks the attribute, the compiler normally won't be able to issue a diagnostic based on the attribute (since it hasn't seen it).

§[dcl.attr.nodiscard]/1:

> The attribute-token nodiscard may be applied to the declarator-id in a **function declaration** or to the declaration of a class or enumeration.

The same basic notion applies to *most* other attributes as well, but a few belong in the implementation--most obviously the `[[fallthrough]]` attribute, which goes at the end of a case in a switch statement, so it has to be located where the switch statement itself is.

The `[[noreturn]]` attribute is a little bit more specific. It directly requires that if a function is declared more than once, the *first* declaration the compiler sees for that function must have the `[[noreturn]]` attribute. If the compiler sees a `[[noreturn]]` attribute on a function that has previously been declared without it, the code is ill-formed (but no diagnostic is required if the two declarations were in separate translation units).